# Where do i put the admin login page on my web app

Tags: php, admin

i just want some insights or advice for my web app. I'm currently working with an web application for a school more like a student portal where in a student can `login` their account, and then view their grades and some other stuff. All the user page is done and now i need to work more on the admin page. My question is:

1. Do i need to use the same `login` page as used by the user (student) and then redirect to admin page if the user is admin?
2. Or just create a separate `login` page for the admin?
3. Or is it good to have a separate folder for the admin like `http://localhost/portal/admin/`?

I hope that you would get my point :D . I just need some advice from any of you who already done some admin page. Thanks in advance.. :D

Comment: `http://localhost/portal/admin/` it will be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to make admin in different folder, But If you are keeping all user in one table of database for student and admin then you can go for 1 login page and after login success you can redirect to admin or student by checking type of user.

Answer (score 1):

I think separate folder is the better way for admin and also you should create the folder name  to some other word but not to admin.

like  "http://mydomain.com/portal/superadmin/"